# Nicifying execution contex's thread pool's output for logging/debuging in scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, debugging, threadpool

Is there is nice way to rename a pool in/for an `executon context` to produce nicer output in logs/wile debugging. Not to be look like ForkJoinPool-2-worker-7 (because **~2** tells nothing about pool's purose in app) but **WorkForkJoinPool**-2-worker-7.. wihout creating new WorkForkJoinPool class for it?

Example:

```
object LogSample extends App {

  val ex1 = ExecutionContext.global
  val ex2 = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(null:Executor) // another global ex context

  val system = ActorSystem("system")

  val log = Logging(system.eventStream, "my.nice.string")

  Future {
    log.info("1")
  }(ex1)

  Future {
    log.info("2")
  }(ex2)

  Thread.sleep(1000)

  // output, like this:

  /*
   [INFO] [09/14/2015 21:53:34.897] [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-7] [my.nice.string] 2
   [INFO] [09/14/2015 21:53:34.897] [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7] [my.nice.string] 1
  */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement custom thread factory, something like this:

```
class CustomThreadFactory(prefix: String) extends ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory {
    def newThread(fjp: ForkJoinPool): ForkJoinWorkerThread = {
      val thread = new ForkJoinWorkerThread(fjp) {}
      thread.setName(prefix + "-" + thread.getName)
      thread
    }
  }

  val threadFactory = new CustomThreadFactory("custom prefix here")

  val uncaughtExceptionHandler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    override def uncaughtException(t: Thread, e: Throwable) = e.printStackTrace()
  }

  val executor = new ForkJoinPool(10, threadFactory, uncaughtExceptionHandler, true)
  val ex2 = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(executor) // another global ex context

  val system = ActorSystem("system")

  val log = Logging(system.eventStream, "my.nice.string")


  Future {
    log.info("2") //[INFO] [09/15/2015 18:22:43.728] [custom prefix here-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29] [my.nice.string] 2
  }(ex2)

  Thread.sleep(1000)
```

Comment: just note that ForkJoinPool will not work with "blocking" as default global ex contex would do. Future {blocking {...}} - will not create new extra threads if all are busy in current pool

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Seems this is not possible (**particulary for default global iml**) due to [current scala ExecutonContext implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala#L33-L56).

What I could do is just **copy** that impl and replace:

```
class DefaultThreadFactory(daemonic: Boolean) ... {
def wire[T <: Thread](thread: T): T = {
  thread.setName("My" + thread.getId) // ! add this one (make 'My' to be variable)
  thread.setDaemon(daemonic)
  thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(uncaughtExceptionHandler)
  thread
}...
```

because `threadFactory` there

```
val threadFactory = new DefaultThreadFactory(daemonic = true)
```

is harcoded ...

(seems Vladimir Petrosyan was first showing nicer way :) )

Comment: I ended up having this: https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/tree/master/src/main/scala/concurrency/logging